# Change maxRevisions setting per section

Tags: config, revisions

We'd like to keep the revisions feature active on our site, but a few of our content sections are synced with a third-party API and we don't need to keep a revision at all. Is there a way to set maxRevisions to 0 for specific sections?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, I'm afraid as that config setting is taken into account on a per-element (i.e. entry), basis.

Feel free to make a feature request for it here, though: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues